# SWF to image (jpg, png, ...) with PHP

Tags: php, flash

I would like to know if it could be possible to convert an **swf** file, with his **flashvars** to a bitmap **image**. But all that in **PHP**, is it possible ? I precise that I would like to do it several times, and that the .swf file is not mine (is not on my site, I take it from a other site).

I allready thank you for your answers ! :)

Comment: Are you wanting to convert only a single frame of the swf?

Comment: Concretely, it's this : http://bit.ly/jeEJhm

Comment: So which part are you wanting to make into a JPEG/PNG/etc? Most jpeg and png files are static, meaning you would need to pick either a single frame of the SWF to export or you would need to export all frames to a collection of static images.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you will get is with SWFTOOLS: http://www.swftools.org/

It can extract bitmaps and flashvars. There are windows and linux binaries available so you'll have to run it from the commandline, that should not be a problem. The main problem of converting an swf to jpeg is that a lot of flash files require execution of ActionsScript in order to show something usefull, and then still you have to have the right frame, so it might not be so straightforward.

**So my answer would be:** Yes, it might be possible if the movie is very simple and only consists of simple bitmaps. But also no: for most swf's it will be very difficult without a flash client and screenshot capabilities if you really need the output of the movie.